# How do I get additional search engines in my right-click menu on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, search, context-menu

Upon highlighting text in Chrome, right clicking the highlighted text produces "Search {Default Search Engine} for {highlighted text}" in the right-click menu.  I'd like to add several additional providers to that list.  Let's start with just one, though? :)

Would somebody ***please*** walk me through adding an additional search engine to the right-click menu?  Whatever it takes, guys. :)

Thank you, so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could to this with an Chrome Add-On called [Context Menu Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/context-menu-search/ocpcmghnefmdhljkoiapafejjohldoga)

Also read this here: [chrome.contextMenus](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html)

Comment: Seems to be working beautifully.  ;>